# Building some project for my last year in university Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

hi stackoverflow family im following some tutorial in udemy about creating some ecommerce website using MERN stack and i got many problems and if don't finish it im gonna get a 0 as a project in my last year
tutorial[tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/course/mern-ecommerce/learn/lecture/22494062#reviews)

## error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
> at addToCartHandler (ProductScreen.js:19:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
> at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
> at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
> at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
> at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
> at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
> addToCartHandler @ ProductScreen.js:19
> callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
> invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
> invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
> invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
> executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
> processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
> processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
> dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
> (anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
> batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
> batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
> dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
> dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
> dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
> dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430

## code

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row,Col,Image,ListGroup,Card,Button,Form } from "react-bootstrap"
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import axios from "axios"
const ProductScreen = ({history,match}) => {
    const params = useParams();
        const [product,setProduct] = useState({})
        const { id } = useParams();
        const [qty,setQty] = useState(0)
        useEffect(()=>{
            const fetchProduct = async ()=>{
                const {data}= await axios.get('/api/products/'+id)
              setProduct(data) 
            }
            fetchProduct()
          },[])
    const addToCartHandler = () =>{
        history.push(`/cart/${match.params.id}?qty=${qty}`)
    }
    return <>
        <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>Go back</Link>
        <Row>
            <Col md="6">
                <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid/>
            </Col>
            <Col md="3">
                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews}
                        reviews
                        `}/>

                    </ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        Price : ${product.price}
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        Description : ${product.description}
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
                
            </Col>
            <Col md={3}>
                <Card>
                    <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <Row>
                                <Col>
                                Price : 
                                </Col>
                                <Col>
                                <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <Row>
                                <Col>
                                Status : 
                                </Col>
                                <Col>
                                    {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out Of Stock"}
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>Qty</Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <Form.Control as="select" value={qty}
                                    onChange={(e)=> setQty(e.target.value)}>
                                        {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map(x =>(
                                            <option key={x+1} value={x+1}>
                                                {x+1}
                                            </option>
                                        ))}
                                    </Form.Control>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                        )}
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <Button onClick={addToCartHandler}
                             className='btn-block' type='button'
                            disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                            >
                                Add To Cart 
                            </Button>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </>;
  };
  

export default ProductScreen
```

Comment: You didn't pass `history` prop to the `ProductScreen` component

Comment: The course author is using `react-router-dom` version `5.x` and you are using version `6.x`. If you want to have the same behaviour use the same version of the package